# Mockar método não estático de uma classe contendo uma chamada de outro metódo estático

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit, mockito

Olá,

O titulo ficou meio confuso, mas vamos lá.
Tenho a classe abaixo:

```
public class ClasseA {

    public static final int constA = ClasseB.metodoB();


    public int metodoA(){
        System.out.println("Passei no metodo A");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de mockar o métodoA, porem não consigo, pois ele sempre chama o método B.

Minha classe de Teste:

```
public class TestesClasses {

    @Mock
    private ClasseA classeA;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testando(){
        Mockito.when(classeA.metodoA()).thenReturn(1);

        int retorno = classeA.metodoA();
        System.out.println("Retorno "+retorno);
    }
}
```

Quero que seja mockado tmb o método B, como se eu quisesse mockar quase a classe inteira.
Já tentei com  o mockito, powermock, etc e nao dá certo...
Se alguem puder me ajudar e colocar como fez a classe de teste, agradeço demais!!!!

Comment: Não entendi. Você deseja o mock do objeto de `ClasseA`? Ou quer fazer o mock do método estático de `ClasseB`?

Comment: Quero mockar o metodo da Classe A, porem quando declaro:

    @Mock
     private ClasseA classeA;
ele chama o metodo B... que tmb quero mockar

Comment: Sua pergunta me gerou essa dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269196/64969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução.

Como ele estava chamando o método antes, coloquei um @BeforeClass como abaixo:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ClasseA.class,ClasseB.class })
public class TestesClasses {

    @Mock
    private ClasseA classeA;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClasseB.class);
        Mockito.mock(ClasseA.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testando(){
        PowerMockito.when(ClasseB.metodoB()).thenReturn(5);     
        Mockito.when(classeA.metodoA()).thenReturn(1);

        int retornoA = classeA.metodoA();
        int retornoB = ClasseB.metodoB();
        System.out.println("Retorno A: "+retornoA);
        System.out.println("Retorno B: "+retornoB);
    }
}
```

Comment: marca que a resposta resolveu o problema. Tem um V abaixo da área de up/down vote para fazer isso.