# Quando usar mock de métodos estáticos?

Tags: testes-de-unidade, mock

@FernandoSchelb recentemente fez a pergunta sobre [como fazer mock de métodos estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269190/64969). Isso me gerou as dúvidas:

- Se podemos fazer, quando devemos fazer?
- Quais são os casos em que mock de método estático é benéfico?
- Quando consigo detectar que o uso desse mock está sendo abusivo?

Comment: Boa pergunta... tenho dúvidas tmb... 
Pq não se testa geralmente métodos estáticos?
Pq será que o mockito não dá suporte, tendo que recorrer a outros frameworks.... :-/

Comment: @FernandoSchelb se tem quem fez, creio que ele foi atrás de atender alguma necessidade. Eu na minha visão limitada não enxergo o porquê disso além de uma modelagem errada, mas creio que exista situações em que é extremamente positivo fazer isso. Mas também que em muitos casos seja só abuso da estrutura

Comment: Posso ter a honra de saber o porquê do negativo? Gostaria de poder melhorar

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "detectar uso abusivo"? Apesar de toda a discussão sobre métodos estáticos, ainda não encontrei um pattern/regra de quando se deve ou não fazer o mock de um método estático. Alguns processos CI/CD exigem 80%+ de code coverage, o que provavelmente vai te obrigar a testar métodos estáticos(com ou sem mocks). Geralmente o mock é benéfico quando o método estático é stateless ou não causa "efeitos colaterais". Em casos onde o método estático é stateful, tem dependências ou causa "efeito colateral", seu mock pode ser um tiro no pé e não representar o comportamento real.

Comment: @FernandoSchelb existe uma [discussão no repositório do mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013) a respeito disso. Aparentemente não querem encorajar o abuso de métodos estáticos. Mas acredito que, se o método estático existe, ele deve ser testado sim.

Comment: "Abusar" quis usar no mesmo sentido de ["abusar do uso de OO"](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/oo-abusers) ou ["abusar do `goto`](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) ou ["abusar do não abuso do `goto`"](https://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf); uso indiscriminado/não recomendado/lesivo para o projeto. "Detectar uso abusivo" então seria uma espécie de procedimento para reconhecer esses usos através da leitura do código/teste/informações satélites e relacionadas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ah, sim! Acho que isso vai depender um pouco das ferramentas que você utiliza. Não tenho certeza, mas no Sonar por exemplo, talvez você consiga configurar métricas/code smell pra detectar o abuso do mock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Métodos estáticos são tão flexíveis quanto granito. Se você precisa fazer o mock de um método estático, é sinal de que há algo errado no projeto.

Um método estático idealmente oferece uma funcionalidade definitiva e imutável. Se você precisa mocká-lo para isolar o seu teste de suas dependências, então é porque ou ele não é definitivo e nem imutável, e portanto não deveria ser estático, ou então não era algo para você mockar.

A ideia de usar mock é isolar o código sob teste de suas dependências. Entretanto, é importante frisar-se que há diferentes tipos de dependências e nem todas valem a pena serem mockadas.

Por exemplo, imaginemos esse código:

```java
package com.example.meucodigo;

public class MinhaClasse {
    public static double sincos(int a) {
        double r = Math.sin(a);
        double s = Math.cos(a);
        return r + s;
    }
}
```

Naturalmente, como pode se ver, ele retorna a soma do seno e do co-seno de um número. A forma adequada de testá-lo (com JUnit 5) seria assim:

```java
package com.example.teste;

import com.example.meucodigo.MinhaClasse;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TesteSinCos {
    @Test
    public void teste0() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1.0, MinhaClasse.sincos(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void teste30() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(Math.srqt(3) / 2 + 0.5, MinhaClasse.sincos(Math.PI / 6));
    }

    @Test
    public void teste45() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(Math.sqrt(2), MinhaClasse.sincos(Math.PI / 4));
    }

    @Test
    public void teste90() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1.0, MinhaClasse.sincos(Math.PI / 2));
    }
}
```

Observe que no teste acima não foi usado mock e ele nem mesmo se preocupa em saber que a implementação usa `Math.sin` e `Math.cos`. Usar o mock nesse caso seria um abuso, pois o uso de `Math.sin` e `Math.cos` é uma parte imutável e interna do método exercitado. Se mockassemos essas funções, estaríamos basicamente testando um método de adição simples, e não testando a funcionalidade realmente oferecida pelo método. Além disso, sob o ponto de quem utiliza o método, externo a ele, a dependência de determinado método estático é um detalhe encapsulado da implementação. Projetar a API de forma que isso possa ser mockado (ou seja, injetando-se os métodos de seno e co-seno na classe `MinhaClasse`) é ruim e resulta em um aumento da complexidade sem real benefício, tornando a classe em questão mais difícil de ser usada, mais difícil de ser instanciada e mais difícil de ser testada. Você deve projetar classes e métodos que possam ser testadas sem violar o encapsulamento natural deles.

No entanto, obviamente, há diversos casos onde o uso de mocks justifica-se, em especial quando a dependência é algo polimórfico, excessivamente complexo, que depende de estado externo e/ou que têm métodos que quando utilizados, produzem efeitos colaterais em objetos que não sejam os seus parâmetros. Por exemplo:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Conexao {
    public static Connection conectar() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class ClienteDAO {

    private static final String INADIMPLENTES_SQL = "SELECT * FROM BLABLA";

    public List<Cliente> listarInadimplentes() {
        List<Cliente> inadimplentes = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
            Connection c = Conexao.conectar();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(INADIMPLENTES_SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        )
        {
            // ...
        }
        return inadimplentes;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, o `ClienteDAO` depende do método estático `Conexao.conectar()`. Ele também depende de uma `String` que está chapada em seu código.

Esse é um caso típico de onde o uso do mock é desejável e o uso do método estático causa problemas. A melhor solução seria eliminar o uso do método estático e usar injeção de dependência no lugar:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class ClienteDAO {

    private static final String INADIMPLENTES_SQL = "SELECT * FROM BLABLA";

    private final Supplier<Connection> conector;

    public ClienteDao(Supplier<Connection> conector) {
        this.conector = conector;
    }

    public List<Cliente> listarInadimplentes() {
        List<Cliente> inadimplentes = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
            Connection c = conector.get();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(INADIMPLENTES_SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        )
        {
            while (rs.next()) {
                // ...
            }
        }
        return inadimplentes;
    }
}
```

E então, você pode mockar o `Supplier<Connection>` com uma implementação que fornece um `Connection` mockado que produz `PreparedStatement`s mockados que produzem `ResultSet`s mockados. Isso ainda dá bastante trabalho, mas não deve ser muito difícil de fazer com o mockito e te livra da necessidade de ter um banco de dados real e te dá controle sobre as dependências.

Em geral, a abordagem a ser usada com métodos que fabricam objetos polimórficos é essa. Ao invés de depender de um método estático de fábrica ou de um singleton, você troca isso por injeção de dependências. Ou seja, a solução não é mockar o método estático ou o singleton, e sim eliminar o seu uso!

Ainda há a SQL estática no código acima. A rigor essa SQL deveria ser um detalhe da implementação encapsulado no `ClienteDAO`. O problema é que ela "vaza" e torna-se visível para as suas dependências. A solução seria colocá-la em uma classe a parte e injetá-la (tem a vantagem de tornar as SQLs mais flexíveis, mas aumenta-se a complexidade) ou então colocar o modificador `public` nela (mais simples, mas menos flexível e pode atentar contra o encapsulamento).

É verdade que há muitas coisas que uma classe pode fazer que dependem de métodos estáticos, construtores e singletons que se fossem todos refatorados para serem injetados como dependências, acabaria produzindo algo com tantos pontos de injeção de dependências e com tanto polimorfismo em excesso que praticamente não seria mais usável. Parte da solução para isso é:

- Preferir usar classes de dados imutáveis, algo que simplifica bastante os testes, elimina bastante a necessidade de você querer ou precisar mockar muitas coisas e elimina bastante o excesso de polimorfismo. Nesses casos, quando o construtor (que podem ser múltiplos e com diversos parâmetros, se necessário) finalizarem a sua execução, o objeto tem que estar pronto para ser usado e não necessitar de nenhuma alteração a mais. Se precisar de alterar um objeto, pense em criar novos objetos derivativos semelhantes ao invés de alterar. Veja mais sobre isso [**nessa outra resposta minha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132).
- Eliminar métodos e objetos estáticos mutáveis ou que produzem efeitos colaterais ao colocá-los como parte de um "mundo", de um contexto. Por exemplo, se o seu processamento de folha de pagamento define uma variável estática mutável contendo o arquivo a ser processado e coloca em outras variáveis estáticas mutáveis as linhas processadas, a solução seria criar uma classe `FolhaDePagamento` e nela colocar uma variável de instância contendo o arquivo a ser processado e em outras variáveis de instância as linhas processadas. Ou seja, muitas vezes, as variáveis estáticas e os métodos que acompanham podem ser agrupados em um mundinho representado por uma instância de um objeto não-singleton. Isso tende a eliminar muitos casos de ocorrência de métodos estáticos, além de melhorar a organização do código.
- Preferir especificar objetos com comportamentos altamente polimórficos por meio de interfaces. Isso é algo um tanto básico de programação orientada a objetos, mas muitas vezes esquecido e/ou negligenciado.
- Utilizar lambdas e *method references* para casos onde o polimorfismo desejado seja algo simples.
- Substituir a fabricação de objetos por meio de métodos estáticos e construtores por *factories*. Um exemplo disso é o do `ClienteDAO` refatorado acima.

Em geral, ter métodos estáticos que produzem efeitos colaterais, dependem de estados externos ou que envolvam polimorfismo é um sinal de que coisas erradas estão acontecendo no seu projeto e que refatorações são necessárias para eliminá-los. Já os métodos estáticos que não produzem efeitos colaterais, não envolvem polimorfismo e nem dependem de estado externo não deveriam ter razão para serem mockados.

Quanto aos singletons e enums, estes, bem como quaisquer outros objetos estáticos, também deveriam ser imutáveis e não depender de qualquer estado externo.

Há casos como um método que utilize [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) que podem parecer complicados. Esse método produz efeitos colaterais apenas em seu parâmetro, mas não depende de estado externo e nem é algo polimórfico. Ele é um caso análogo ao [`Math.sin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin-double-), e portanto não deve ser mockado.

Indo na [pergunta que você usou como exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269190/132), vamos ver o que há no código e na solução encontrada:

```java
public class ClasseA {

    public static final int constA = ClasseB.metodoB();


    public int metodoA(){
        System.out.println("Passei no metodo A");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ClasseA.class,ClasseB.class })
public class TestesClasses {

    @Mock
    private ClasseA classeA;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClasseB.class);
        Mockito.mock(ClasseA.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testando(){
        PowerMockito.when(ClasseB.metodoB()).thenReturn(5);     
        Mockito.when(classeA.metodoA()).thenReturn(1);

        int retornoA = classeA.metodoA();
        int retornoB = ClasseB.metodoB();
        System.out.println("Retorno A: "+retornoA);
        System.out.println("Retorno B: "+retornoB);
    }
}
```

Esse exemplo é bastante artificial, então não dá para dizer com certeza o que de fato deveria ter sido, mas vou tentar usá-lo mesmo assim. O problema aqui é que o `metodoB()` fornece uma constante que não é exatamente uma constante, uma vez que, dada a necessidade de mocká-lo, conclui-se que o seu comportamento talvez seja polimórfico. O certo seria haver uma instância de `ClasseB` ou de alguma outra classe onde o `metodoB()` fosse chamado como um método de instância. Quanto ao `constA`, dado que isso dependeria então de uma instância de `ClasseB`, logo ele corresponde a parte de um contexto no qual as instâncias de `ClasseA` são usadas e criadas, e portanto `ClasseB` ou seria uma dependência de `ClasseA` ou então seria responsável por fabricar objetos de `ClasseA`.

Agora, respondendo diretamente às suas perguntas:

> Se podemos fazer, quando devemos fazer?

Idealmente nunca. Faça isso só quando não houver outra saída, como no caso de o código a ser testado não poder ser modificado ou não for viável de ser modificado.

> Quais são os casos em que mock de método estático é benéfico?

Nunca. Isso é uma má prática de programação e só deve ser usada em último caso quando o código a ser testado não puder ou não for viável de ser modificado.

> Quando consigo detectar que o uso desse mock está sendo abusivo?

Ele sempre é abusivo.

Answer (score 3):

Vou partir do princípio que não iremos entrar no mérito de como refatorar um código com métodos estáticos, pois eu entendo que isto seria uma outra discussão.

Vamos as suas perguntas.

> Se podemos fazer, quando devemos fazer?

Normalmente você precisa de um mock de método estático quando ele guarda muita complexidade que simplesmente tentar contorná-la acaba não sendo viável.

> Quais são os casos em que mock de método estático é benéfico?

Exemplo de uma classe que usa método estático complexo:

```java
class ClassComEstatico () {

    public void metodo(String variavel) {
        //algum codigo simples
        BigDecimal valor = CalcularUtils.calculoComplexo(variavel); // problema...
    }
}
```

O `CalcularUtils.calculoComplexo(variavel)` pode ser um verdadeiro buraco negro, chamando outros Singletons, dependendo de outros métodos estáticos, chamando services por `ServiceLocator`... a imaginação é o limite. E em um teste você teria que lidar com todas estas dependências escondidas deste método aparentemente inofensivo. Neste caso, acaba sendo benéfico criar um mock para ele.

Se o método do `CalcularUtils` fosse um simples `arredondar(variavel)` você não precisaria se preocupar em mockar ele, dada a simplicidade do método. Por isto normalmente não nos preocupamos em mockar os `Utils`/`Helpers`.

> Quando consigo detectar que o uso desse mock está sendo abusivo?

Entendo que isto começa a ocorrer quando seu `setup` de teste acaba tendo muitos mocks de métodos estáticos. Isto pode gerar uma confusão muito grande, porque você não saberá identificar facilmente qual estático mockado corresponde a qual parte do seu código sendo testado pelo teste unitário. Exemplo:

```java
@Test
public void teste() {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassComEstaticos1.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassComEstaticos2.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassComEstaticos3.class);

    Resultado resultado = service.calcular(1, 2);
    //asserts
}
```

Assim, vêem as perguntas: Quem precisa do `ClassComEstaticos1`? E do `ClassComEstaticos2`? E do `ClassComEstaticos3`? É o próprio método `calcular()` que precisa ou é algum método que o `calcular` chama internamente? Ou ainda é outra classe que o `calcular` usa? E qual destes mocks ele usa?

Isto fará com que seja extremamente difícil de manter os testes. Abusivo ou não, se você precisar fazer o teste não terá como desviar deles a menos que consiga reescrever o código e removendo os métodos estáticos.