# Quando uma classe utilitária deve tornar-se uma dependência injetável?

Tags: java, spring, testes-de-unidade, injeção-de-dependência, refatoração

Muitas vezes, eu escrevo pequenas classes utilitárias para resolver algum problema menor no meu código. Por exemplo (vou utilizar Spring para DI):

```
@Service
class PessoaService {

    public PessoaResponse converter(Pessoa pessoa, Long valor1, Long valor2) {
        PessoaResponse pessoaResponse = new PessoaMapperUtil(pessoa).toResponse();
        Long resultado = valor1 + valor2;
        pessoaResponse.setResultado(resultado);
        return pessoaResponse;
    }

}
```

Meu `PessoaMapperUtil` é bem simples, ele apenas converte os dados da `Pessoa` para uma nova classe `PessoaResponse`, usando um mapper interno.

Contudo, digamos que o `PessoaMapperUtil` comece a ficar mais complexo porque o `Pessoa` começa a ficar maior, atrapalhando meus testes unitários do método `converter`, pois cada vez mais preciso incluir mais campos no `Pessoa` para que o `PessoaMapperUtil` funcione.

Ficando mais complexo, precisarei identificar o momento no qual vai valer a pena fazer o `PessoaMapperUtil` virar uma dependência e ser "mockável", ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
@Service
class PessoaService {

    private final PessoaMapperUtil mapper;

    @AutoWired
    PessoaService(PessoaMapperUtil mapper) { this.mapper = mapper; }

    public PessoaResponse converter(Pessoa pessoa, Long valor1, Long valor2) {
        PessoaResponse pessoaResponse = mapper.toResponse(pessoa);
        Long resultado = valor1 + valor2;
        pessoaResponse.setResultado(resultado);
        return pessoaResponse;
    }
}
```

Fazendo com que `PessoaMapperUtil` vire um componente (`@Component`), fica mais simples mocká-lo e a partir disto eu me preocuparia apenas com o restante do código.

Enfim, qual seria o sintoma no código no qual um utilitário deve virar uma dependência? Atualmente eu faço isto quando ele começa a atrapalhar os testes... É isto mesmo?

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/132) (não é duplicata).

Comment: [Outra pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276787/132) (também não é duplicata).

Comment: É difícil responder isso sem saber ao certo o que há dentro de `PessoaResponse` e `PessoaMapperUtil`. No link do meu comentário anterior, eu falo um pouco sobre modelo anêmico, e acho que é o seu caso aqui.

Comment: Qual o motivo do downvote?

Comment: Eu votei positivo. Receber downvotes aleatórios sem justificativa é sempre muito chato, mas infelizmente não há o que fazer quando isso acontece.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, obrigado! Costumo fazer o mesmo, rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classe `PessoaMapperUtil` não representa um conceito de programação orientada a objetos!

Partindo de um modelo MVC, a classe `Pessoa` é a sua classe responsável por modelar as regras de negócio. Ou seja, está na camada **M**odelo.

A classe `PessoaResponse` seria algo que transporta dados do modelo para fora, em direção a camada de visão, e portanto é algo que está na camada do **C**ontrolador, juntamente com o `PessoaService`.

A classe `PessoaMapperUtil` tem como finalidade pegar algo da camada de modelo (`Pessoa`) e fabricar um objeto da camada controladora (`PessoaResponse`).

Como o modelo não deve conhecer o controlador (apenas o contrário é que vale), então a classe `Pessoa` não deve referenciar `PessoaResponse` ou `PessoaMapperUtil`. Até aqui tudo bem.

Entretanto, uma vez que `PessoaResponsse` e `PessoaMapperUtil` estão na mesma camada e no mesmo módulo/JAR/pacote/qualquer-coisa, então começamos a questionar se de fato deveriam ser separados.

Em geral, classes que tenham nomes terminando em `Manager`, `Util`, `Handler`, `Helper` não representam conceitos reais de programação orientada a objetos, sendo frequentemente:

- Uma cassetada de métodos estáticos amontoados (não parece ser o seu caso).
- Um objeto que tem vida curta e que é construído apenas para que um método seja chamado, separando alguma tarefa em duas etapas (a construção e a invocação do método em si) sem muitas razões para tal.
- Alguma outra coisa com sérios problemas de [coesão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).

A sua classe `PessoaMapperUtil` parece ser o segundo caso. Você até instancia isso, mas é só para chamar o método `toResponse()` logo em seguida. Nesse caso, o melhor sseria dar um passo atrás e colocar um método estático:

```
public static PessoaResponse criar(Pessoa p) {
    // ...
}
```

Qual é o melhor lugar para se colocar esse método? Bem, ele é algo que está na camada do controlador e produz uma instância de `PessoaResponse` que já está nessa camada, logo isso deveria ser um método estático (ou um construtor) de `PessoaResponse`, e não uma classe a parte.

Voltando a classe `PessoaService`, vejamos o que ela faz:

```
public PessoaResponse converter(Pessoa pessoa, Long valor1, Long valor2) {
    // 1. Cria um objeto PessoaResponse.
    PessoaResponse pessoaResponse = new PessoaMapperUtil(pessoa).toResponse();
    Long resultado = valor1 + valor2;

    // 2. O objeto PessoaResponse foi criado incompleto!
    // Portanto, conserta ele chamando setters!
    pessoaResponse.setResultado(resultado);

    // 3. Agora sim, o PessoaResponse está completo e pode ser retornado.
    return pessoaResponse;
}
```

Ou seja, o `PessoaMapperUtil(pessoa).toResponse()` não cria o `PessoaResponse` pronto e esse tem que ser finalizado por fora. Ora, a responsabilidade de criar o `PessoaResponse` corretametente e completamente deveria estar na classe `PessoaResponse` (ou mesmo que fosse no `PessoaMapperUtil`), e portanto não deveria ser responsabilidade de `PessoaService` terminar esse serviço inacabado (veja mais sobre isso [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132)). A responsabilidade de `PessoaService` deveria ser apenas a de expor funcionalidades da aplicação ao Spring e nada mais que isso.

Ou seja, o ideal seria você ter isso na classe `PessoaResponse`:

```
public static PessoaResponse criar(Pessoa p, Long valor1, Long valor2) {
    Long resultado = valor1 + valor2;
    // ...
}
```

Com isso sua classe `PessoaService` fica assim:

```
@Service
class PessoaService {
    public PessoaResponse converter(Pessoa pessoa, Long valor1, Long valor2) {
        return PessoaResponse.criar(pessoa, valor1, valor2);
    }
}
```

Ok, mas e aí, como mockamos isso? Nesse caso caímos no que explanei [nessa resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273527/132), não deveria fazer sentido mockar método estático. Nesse caso, se quisessemos mockar ele, a própria classe `PessoaService` testada não faria nenhum sentido. Ela não seria nada mais do que algo que retornaria de forma burra e cega, qualquer tranqueira que o mock lhe devolvesse sem olhar nada mais e nem fazer qualquer crítica ou verificação. Ou seja, ao mockar o método que ela chama, produziríamos um teste inócuo. O motivo é que o que tem que ser testado aqui é o método `PessoaResponse.criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)`, para certificar-se que o `PessoaResponse` produzido está correto. A classe `PessoaService` se reduz a apenas uma forma muito verbosa de dizer ao Spring que o método `criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)` da classe `PessoaResponse` é uma funcionalidade exposta como serviço.

E para testar o método `criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)` da classe `PessoaResponse`? Simples, crie um objeto `Pessoa` (aqui pode ser um mock sem problemas), passe-o para esse método e faça um monte de `assertXXX`s no objeto retornado. Note que testar se o `PessoaResponse` retornado está certo, é muito mais fácil se ele for uma classe imutável - sem setters, com todos os campos `final` e sem quaisquer outras coisas que possam modificar uma instância após o construtor terminar de executar, ainda mais considerando que a finalidade para a qual a classe `PessoaResponse` existe é para transportar dados para outras partes da aplicação que devem estar desacopladas da origem dos mesmos. Adotar-se essa prática faz com que o problema de criar objetos incompletos seja sanado e impede que ele seja reintroduzido por descuido.

Assim sendo, para testar o método `converter(Pessoa, Long, Long)` da classe `PessoaService` é só fazer os mesmos testes que foram realizados com `criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)` da classe `PessoaResponse`, afinal de contas os dois devem ter exatamente o mesmo comportamento sem tirar e nem pôr nada.

Melhor ainda seria você conseguir convencer o Spring a usar o método `criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)` da classe `PessoaResponse` como serviço por meio de alguma anotação sem precisar da classe `PessoaService`, mas acho que isso daí já é algo que não dá para convencer o Spring a engolir (ao menos não facilmente). Com outros frameworks, pode ser que você consiga ou não.

Sei que isso pouco diz sobre o que acontece quando a complexidade da classe `Pessoa` começar a ficar grande demais, mas isso seria algo que ficaria na responsabilidade de `PessoaResponse` mapear. Entretanto, nesse caso, você teria que fornecer mais dados sobre a sua aplicação.

Bem, ainda há o caso de você realmente não querer de forma alguma colocar o método `criar(Pessoa, Long, Long)` na classe `PessoaResponse` (talvez porque as duas não devam se conhecer de forma nenhuma). Aí sim, nesse caso, você teria que colocar esse método numa classe a parte, mas isso tende a prejudicar a coesão e o encapsulamento de `PessoaResponse`.